# How to setup Apache Nifi behind Cloudflare?

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudflare

I've successfully setup and running a secure (TLS) Apache Nifi server (1.9.2) **without** Cloudflare's DNS protection. Its running well using either ports: 8443 or 2053 which are supported free by Cloudflare. But once I've put the server behind Cloudflare's DNS, its showing:

> Error 1105
>
> Temporarily unavailable

Any clue?